# How to change apk file name in android

Tags: android

I need to change the name of apk file for my android application.
I am using Eclipse for the build.
How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 8):

Right click your project, Android tools --> Export unsigned application --> name it whatever you want.apk

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project. Then choose "**Rename**", type new name. After that in directory [new name]/bin will be generated [new name].apk

Comment: question is about the change apk name, not project name.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project, then select android tools, then select Export Signed Application Package. If you slect Unsigned Application Package, then you will able to change the name of apk but wont able to install on unrooted phone as CERTIFICATE error will come. After selecting "Export Signed Application Package", You will get option to sign your apk. Sign it with existing default android key. The location of key is normally C/users/youruserid/.android/debug.store. "debug.store" is the key. Password for key is "android". After that in next window, select alias name from dropdown. It is "androiddebugkey". The password for it is same "android". Then provide the apk destination folder, provide your apk name and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Use APK editor to change APK files name and icon. But be sure when you change the file icon it must be `.png` format.